# How can I extract internal contours (holes) with python opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

is there an easy and direct way to extract the internal contours (holes) from an image using opencv 3.1 python ?

I know that I can use "area" as a condition. However, if I change the image resolution, the "areas" are not the same.

For instance, with this image:
[image]
How can I extract the internal holes?

```
_, contours, hier_ = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas = [cv2.contourArea(c) for c in millCnts]
max_area = np.max(areas)
Mask = np.ones(img.shape[:2], dtype="uint8") * 255

   # I can do something like this (currently not working, just to show an example)
for c in contours:
    if(( cv2.contourArea(c) > 8) and (cv2.contourArea(c)< 100000)):
        cv2.drawContours(Mask ,[c],-1,0,1)
```

Comment: You can always use the hierarchy values to know if they are nested (holes) or not (outer one)... not sure if already find contours gets all of the contours correctly (you should show that output) but if it does, you can check if the countour ´c´ is nested by checking the corresponding hierarchy ´h´, the 4th value (`h[3]`) if it is non negative.

Comment: I think my main problem is understanding how hierarchy works.
The ouput array is huge :\
At this particular case it won't work .
The limits should be between 8000 and 9000 probably !

Comment: where is `millCnts` defined? can you show an image of all the contours found?

Answer (score 7):

As I explained in my comment, you have to check the hierarchy return variable. After find contours you will get the contours (List of List of Points) and hierarchy (List of List).

The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) is very clear in this:

> hierarchy – Optional output vector, containing information about the
>   image topology. It has as many elements as the number of contours. For
>   each i-th contour contours[i] , the elements `hierarchy[i][0]` ,
>   `hiearchy[i][1]` , `hiearchy[i][2]` , and `hiearchy[i][3]` are set to
>   0-based indices in contours of the next and previous contours at the
>   same hierarchical level, the first child contour and the parent
>   contour, respectively. If for the contour i there are no next,
>   previous, parent, or nested contours, the corresponding elements of
>   hierarchy[i] will be negative.

So, this means that for each `countour[i]` you should get a `hierarchy[i]` that contains a List with 4 variables:

- `hierarchy[i][0]`: the index of the next contour of the same level
- `hierarchy[i][1]`: the index of the previous contour of the same level
- `hierarchy[i][2]`: the index of the first child
- `hierarchy[i][3]`: the index of the parent

So, saying that, in your case, there should be one without a parent, and you can check which one by checking the `hierarchy[i][3]` if it is negative.

It should be something like (untested code):

```
holes = [contours[i] for i in range(len(contours)) if hierarchy[i][3] >= 0]
```

*** UPDATE:***

To summarize what we discussed in the chat,

- The image was too big, and the contours had small holes: solved with dilate and erode with a kernel of size 75
- The image needed to be inverted since OpenCV expects for dilate a black background
- The algorithm was giving 2 big contours, one outside (as expected) and one inside (almost the same as the outside one), this is probably due to the image having some external (and closed) bumps. This was solved by removing the contour without a parent and its first child.

Comment: I think that I'm understading how it works, however It is not clear how can it be done comparasions.
I know that you didn't test code, but the output is :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @marco why would it be ambiguous, it should be a List of Lists as far as I know.... Can you print `len(contours)` and `len(hier_)` it should be the same, or something is wrong there, and also you can try to do `len(_hier[0])` it should be 4

Comment: The contours ' len is 1335 and hier it's 1, and hier[0] it's 1335

Comment: @marco, wow, 1335 is too many contours for that image.... can you print `len(_hier[0][0])`, hopefully this is 4 and then you will have to change to `hierarchy[0][i][3]`. However, I will be kind of weird if you think of the output explained in the documentation....

Comment: I find it wierd. But I think it works.
The code is : holes = [millCnts[i] for i in range(len(millCnts)) if hier[0][i][3] >= 0]
However, I don't know how to draw "holes", because ther are a list, and the drawCountours only accepts countours or numpy

Comment: @marco, you can use the numpy function asarray to convert list to numpy array.... or `numpy.array(c)` instead of `[c]` in your code

Comment: It didn't work , the code. With the condition all the contours are draw. All the contours appears on the image.

Comment: The len of holes is 1334, just minus 1 than len of countours.

Comment: @marco the idea was to separate it from the outer contour, so, in theory the extra contour is the outer one....  but if you are getting that huge amount with your example images, then i recommend some preprocessing, like dilate+erode, and maybe some thresholding to get just a binary image

Comment: I'm using a binary image to extract the contours. I did not post all the code to be concise.
The image has a high resolution.
The result of   holes = [millCnts[i] for i in range(len(millCnts)) if hier[0][i][3] >= 0] cv2.drawContours(HolesMask,np.array(holes),-1,0,3) is :https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/HolesMask.jpg

Comment: @marco, are you drawing it on top of the previos image?, can you draw the contours with another color that is noticeable, preferly each in a different random color, to be able to distinguish the contours, or better, draw the contour that was removed. Also, try using the `dilate` a `erode` functions or `morphologyEx` one that already combines this

Comment: This is a different image, I created a mask.
However, for you being able to see, I've changed the code: cv2.drawContours(colorMask,countours,-1,(0,255,0),12) cv2.drawContours(colorMask,np.array(holes),-1,(255,0,0),6), SO the output is : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/overlaiedContours.jpg

Comment: @marco There is your problem.... the one left out is the contour of the whole image (green)..... it is weird that it considers that one as the outer contour.... But it could be, that it can't generate a well defined 2 level hierarchy, since it has some contours at the same level... (not sure about this) you can try with a different approach for example `CV_RETR_TREE` that will establish all possible hierarchies

Comment: Changing to CV_RETR_TREE the results are equal.

Comment: have you tried the `dilate` function I told you before?, it could be that it is not closed in part, because you should get around 20 contours, not 1335.... this means it is getting only parts of the contours....

Comment: Good news. Results are different. Not what we want xD
Updated code:http://pastebin.com/zH8AHpz1
Updated IMG:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/710615/overlaiedContours_2.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111758/discussion-between-api55-and-marco).